# UIScrollView and UIPageControl, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a class which is predefining some labels and binding their values in a UIScrollView.

I've managed to show those labels, but now I'm stuck at putting a label at the 2nd part of the ScrollView.

I've pushed my project to [gitHub](https://github.com/daneoke/xcode-project).

I can change the label's place on the already visible part, but I must be overlooking something.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = _detail.name;
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor *txtColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    frame.size.width = _scrollView.frame.size.width *2;



    NSString *phoneNr = (_detail.phoneNr == nil) ? @"Not specified" : _detail.phoneNr;

    _telLabel = [self prepareLabel:phoneNr textColor:txtColor bgColor:bgColor page:0 y:telNrYAxis];


    _webLabel = [self prepareLabel:@"Visit website" textColor:txtColor bgColor:bgColor page:0 y:websiteYAxis];

    _detail.address = [_detail.address stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n\t "]];
    NSArray *addressArrComponents = [_detail.address componentsSeparatedByString:@","] ;



    _addressLabel =  [self prepareLabel:[addressArrComponents componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] textColor:txtColor bgColor:bgColor page:0 y:addressYAxis];


    UILabel *lbl = [self prepareLabel:@"Derp" textColor:txtColor bgColor:bgColor page:1 y:0];


    _detailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [_detailView addSubview:_webLabel];
    [_detailView addSubview:_addressLabel];
    [_detailView addSubview:_telLabel];
    [_detailView addSubview:lbl];

    [_scrollView addSubview:_detailView];
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height - (_scrollView.frame.origin.y + _scrollView.frame.size.height) );

    _pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height - 250 , self.view.frame.size.width/4, 120)];
    _pageControl.numberOfPages=2;
    _pageControl.currentPage=0;


    [_pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(800,800);
    _scrollView.delegate=self;
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;

    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    [self pageChange:0];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageControl];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(UILabel*)prepareLabel:(NSString*) text textColor:(UIColor*)textColor bgColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor page:(int)page y:(int) yPos{
    int lines = [[text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(_detailView.frame.size.width * page +20,yPos,self.view.frame.size.width, [UIFont systemFontSize]*lines);

    UILabel *returnLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    returnLabel.text = text;
    returnLabel.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    returnLabel.textColor = textColor;


    [returnLabel setNumberOfLines:lines];
    [returnLabel sizeToFit];

    return returnLabel;
}
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    NSLog(@"Derped");
}

-(IBAction)pageChange:(id)sender{

    int page=_pageControl.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = _scrollView.frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    //CGRect frame= (page == 0) ? _detailFrame : _reviewFrame;
    NSLog(@"%f",frame.origin.x);
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

The delegate `-(IBAction)pageChange:(id)sender` gets fired, but I must be doing something wrong with the frames somewhere :s

Please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this method may help you :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width; 
    float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, though I don't think that'd be the solution. (I tried and it isn't). I think I might be overlooking something related to the frames, but wether it is the label not being placed correctly or the frame not being big enough (the latter is logically not possible due to it being initialized twiced the width of the scrollView, but you never know). Cheers